# how to exclude logger categories from server.log on JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final

Tags: java, logging, jboss7.x

Im working with JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final and there is no chance to change it.

I've tried to configure standalone.xml for create different log files for a different categories. My issue is this: the ouputs for each logger are appened correctly on the specified files, but are also written on server.log file.

There is my entire logging subsystem configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="REQUEST" autoflush="true">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%m%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file path="/Logs/requests.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="ALARMS" autoflush="true">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%m%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file path="/Logs/alarms.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com.maucho.alarm" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="ALARMS"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.maucho.request" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="REQUEST"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="sun.rmi">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.hp.autopassj">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.as.server.deployment">
        <level name="ERROR"/>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

When start AS, standalone.xml file is overwritten and replace logger tags without the attribute use-parent-handlers="false" with nothing, setting the behavior to its default value, use-parent-handlers="true":

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="REQUEST" autoflush="true">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%m%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file path="/Logs/requests.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="ALARMS" autoflush="true">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%m%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file path="/Logs/alarms.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com.maucho.alarm">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="ALARMS"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.maucho.request">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="REQUEST"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="sun.rmi">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.hp.autopassj">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.as.server.deployment">
        <level name="ERROR"/>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

The documentation is very poor and says that i only need to put the parameter use-parent-handlers="false" but it does not work.

Additionaly, I also changed on my code org.apache.log4j.Logger to org.apache.commons.logging.Log with org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory and had the same result, log outputs in both files (/Logs/requests.log or /Logs/alarms.log AND server.log).

My references:
https://community.jboss.org/message/731527
http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html

Comment: Setting the `use-parent-handler=false` should do the trick. Could you paste maybe a small portion of the output you expect to not be written to the server.log?

Comment: This is the log that i get on the log file and also written on server log:  [user@hostname ~]$ tail -f /Logs/alarms.log
13:33:43 11092012|Remote host|fatal|5000|Error al conectar al servidor remoto Connection refused|192.168.100.45:8080

Comment: i'd open standalone.xml with vi and i saw the logger's tags overwritten like this:  <logger category="com.maucho.alarm">

Comment: When you change the value in the standalone.xml is the server stopped or running?

Comment: the server is stopped when i change the standalone.xml

Comment: Hmmm... ...that seems odd. I just tried changing the value and it worked for me. I had `<logger category="com.maucho.alarm" use-parent-handler="false">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="ALARMS"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>`

Comment: what version of JBoss do you have? Im working with "JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final", i have no chance to migrate to a recent version. Do you have a different idea to solve it? I tried adding a <filter><not><match pattern="com.hp.wsutilities"></match></not> on <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true"> but parser does not accept it and AS stop initializing.

Comment: That is the version I tested on. It worked for setting the `use-parent-handler="false"` attribute when the server was shut down. As far as the filter is concerned, I think there may have been a bug in that filter in that release, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Is there some fix that i can download to solve my issue?

Comment: There shouldn't be, it should just work. I would just absolutely make sure your app server is down, then edit the XML, save and relaunch.

Comment: that is what i do but takes no effect, over write standalone.xml configuration file. I down the AS, edit the standalone.xml with vi, save and close it, open it just for make sure changes are saved, close, start AS and see diplicated logs in server.log and alarms.log, also open standalone.xml file and realize that use-parent-handler="false" attribute is deleted :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very old thread but just in case anyone is looking for a solution to this problem. There is a typo in the property name, a missing 's'. Here is the property to set to get it working-
use-parent-handler**s**=false